# What is unclear about this question?

Tags: discussion

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/whats-the-best-way-to-structure-an-email-that-has-suggestions-for-workplace-pro

Answer (score 3):

What I think might make this a little unclear is that your question seems to be something that you could answer by doing a Google search on some persuasive communication techniques. I didn't close the post, but I suspect that the people who did vote to close may believe there's more to the question than what you've given us, and to them, that may mean it's a bit unclear. No one likes to answer a question only to have the asker say, "No! I already thought about trying X, but that won't work because my problem consists of Y."

Let's assume you already did some research on communication techniques and discovered some helpful information but are just unsure of how to apply those techniques. If you can edit your post to describe why it is your stuck, it will make it more clear to the answerers exactly what it is that you don't understand but on a much deeper level.

Not only will this likely get you a really great answer, but it will also be more helpful for others who have a similar issue that wasn't solved by simply reading some guidelines on good persuasive communication.

Comment: It's not that I'm stuck, I just want a good answer - A frame work for writing these emails.

Comment: Let me be a bit more direct. Why didn't you just Google this? Don't take that question the wrong way. the reason I ask is because if you can tell us why something like this http://nptweeklytrancemission.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/5-keys-to-writing-more-persuasive-emails/ doesn't answer your question, it will help make things more clear as to why you need more advanced help than what Google already provides.

Comment: Not saying this is the sole reason why the community put your question on hold, it's just something I saw that *may* help clarify. I'll post this link to this meta discussion under your post on the main site to see if anyone else can help provide more guidance. Hope this helps!

Comment: Another thing you could do to help clarify is maybe tell us about your corporate culture. Why do you feel like your input would be taken harshly? It actually sounds like you work in a very open-minded organization, which makes it difficult to understand why you're concerned about this. Have you upset someone with previous emails perhaps? Have your manager talked to you about your approach in emails? Details like this may be helpful to understand why this is a problem. :)

Comment: Would it be useful to turn the answers to this question into a collection of differnt formats for suggesting improvements for the workplace, maybe along with some details on what the individual formats focus on?

Comment: @CMW - If there was reasoning in the answers beyond "this is my favorite format" or "try this" -- if there's some sort of evidence to back up an example, it could work. But, the emphasis should definitely be on the *why* and *how*.

Comment: @jmort253 Yeah, that's exactly what I thought of

Comment: @jmort253 Quick note: make sure to tag people in comments if it's not their question/answer and you're asking them somthing specifically - as it doesn't show up in the inbox otherwise.

Comment: @jmort253 - Certainly it does sound optimistic, though the (somewhat cynical, though, I'm trying not to be, hence I'm writing the email) concern is that while it's all bubbly when we have conferences, back in the day to day, the same old goes on. The reasons I'm cautious: I'm a junior, this is my first job, I was on performance management earlier in the year. See also this question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17024/how-long-is-reasonable-to-expect-for-a-simple-reply-to-an-email

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is now **too broad**.

It is going to be very hard to answer this question because effective varies greatly depending on what you are trying to suggest, and persuasive is going to vary based on who you are trying to convince.

I am not going to cast a reopen vote to a question that still needs to be closed.

Comment: +1: 100% agree. Thanks @Chad!